# How do I get the value of an input element using angular.element('#id')

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I'm trying to get the value of input element using angular.element, its returning undefined.
Here is my code:

```
$scope.registerUser = function() {
    console.log(angular.element('#username').value); // undefined
    console.log(document.getElementById('username').value); // sampleName
};
```

How do I get the value using angular.element

Comment: Is there a model attached to the input? You should be able to grab it that way by scope reference.

Comment: I would like to get the values using angular.element('#id') selector.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Explanation

You should use [`val`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) method similar to jQuery's [`$.fn.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
console.log(angular.element('#username').val());
```

Alternatively you can use `value` property of the pure HTMLInputELement:

```
console.log(angular.element('#username')[0].value);
```

... because `angular.element` instance is an array-like collection of HTMLElements with every element accessible by its index.

#### Correct approach

But... You should never read input value like this in context of Angular app. Instead, use [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive and bind input value to angular model directly:

```
$scope.registerUser = function() {    
    console.log($scope.username);
};
```

where in HTML you have

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username">
```

Comment: But if you are in iframe and you don't have angular in that iframe, what would you do?

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib What is the task?

Comment: I have angular modal that opens inside it an iframe which loads cshtml (.net) page. and after user click save in the model I should bring the data from the page to the angular model.

Comment: I suggest that you create separate question, because it's too broad to answer it in comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No need of jquery

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('username')).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my angular-7 project, I solved by using these statement.

```
var field = document.getElementById('elementId'); 
var currentValue= field.getAttribute('value');
field.setAttribute('value','newValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below options for AngularJS 2+.

`(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByName("username")[0]).value`
`(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsById("username")[0]).value`

Answer (score 0):

The same way as in jQuery, for which `angular.element` is a wrapper/sub:

```
angular.element('#username').val();
```

Comment: This answer can be used if you are working on Angular 1

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above ways,
these may also be used :

```
angular.element('[id="username"]').val();
angular.element('[id="username"]')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use "ViewChild" Decorator.

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'demo-input',
    templateUrl: 'demo.input.component.html'
})
export class DemoInputComponent {
    @ViewChild('inputEle') myDOMEle: ElementRef;

    getInputValue(){
       let val = this.myDOMEle.nativeElement.value;
    }
    setInputValue(){
       this.myDOMEle.nativeElement.value = "testing";
    }
}
```

In HTML(demo.input.component.html)

```
<input type="text" #inputEle/>
```