# Angular2 (JavaScript) - Get the value of an element

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to get the value of a particular element in Angular2, but so far I am stuck in the middle.

Basically, I want to do something as easy as the below (jQuery) but in Angular2

```
    $( "div#elementId" ).val();
```

**Edit** : I am trying to get the value of a `div` which is inside a `<form>`

Comment: see link:
[How do I get the value of an input element using angular.element('#id')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684049/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-an-input-element-using-angular-elementid)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `two way data binding` to access an elements value. In this case i will assume you are trying to access an input's value. you can do this in your template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]='elementName'>
```

and in your exported class do the following

```
export className{
    elementName
    // elementName variable will be same with the input
}
```

I hope this helps or at least gives you an idea. For detailed information about [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: its `[(ngModel)]` not `[{ngModel}]` , edited your answer hope you don't mind.

Comment: it didn't worked for me as I am trying to get the value of a `div` that is inside a form

Comment: then you should take e look ad ngControl and form-control.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to access particular element, the best way do this in angular 2.0 is **attribute directive** 
 see here

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

working plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/at1rkZRhNQ3GniypwlUm/

If you hover over the 'Highlight me' in ex, you can see the changes. Basically `this.el` will give you the corresponding element reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can using angular2 only i think you have to use `ViewChild`, if you want to get any value of say textfield either you have to use `id` for using javascript but in case if angular2 only you can declare local variable using `#` say

```
<input type="text" #name>
```

by using this you can get value of the name field using ViewChild like this :--

```
.....
@ViewChild('name') name: any;
this.name.nativeElement.value;
.....
```

<kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rL0iZdiXjU056ESCZJ9z?p=preview)</kbd>

Alternate

You should use [`val`](http://plnkr.co/edit/rL0iZdiXjU056ESCZJ9z?p=preview) method similar to jQuery's [`$.fn.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
console.log(angular.element('#username').val());
```

see also

- [How do I get the value of an input element using angular.element('#id')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684088/5043867)

Comment: it didn't work, I believe your answer is written in TypeScript; however, the question is about Angular2 for JavaScript

Comment: yes but `viewchild` syntax is same for typescript as well as javascript, and btw i have just posted an idea assuming you are using typescript, for more info refer here https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
 angular.element(document.querySelector('div#elementId'));
```

Comment: That's valid for AngularJS, the question is about Angular2

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried Angular2 yet.  Didn't expect a big difference in this matter, obviously I was wrong.

Comment: of course there are lot of changes in angular2 and angular1.x, your expectation is wrong this time  :p hehe @user2968675 \